# Prestashop 1.4 - Create 3 product page instead of 1 product page

Tags: product, prestashop

I want to create 3 product pages with different content instead of 1 product page.
The first page includes picture, description of product and "continue to next page" button.
The second page includes a Jcrop (Jquery plugin) over picture of product.
The third page includes attributes and price and "Add To Cart" button.
The structure must be similar to: [this site](http://www.jwwalls.com/photographic-view-all/fishermans-bastion)
Each page must can send data to other page.
My question is how to create new pages and how to link them together.
My prestashop version is 1.4.9 .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some hooks to display "hidden" div. Then when you click on button you hide the current page and display the hidden div ? (Using jQuery)

Comment: Thanks not a bad solution.But maybe makes page load time long

Comment: Yes it will be a bit longer to load, what about an iFrame ?

Comment: I am looking for a way to make new tpl such as product2.tpl, product3.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags to distinguish which product page you want to show. This piece of smarty code has worked for me well for PrestaShop 1.4.4

```
{if in_array("colop",$product->tags[6])}
custom product tpl
{/if}
```

If a product has the colop tag the a different page generates. The problem with this solution is that you will end up with a large product.tpl file with a lot of large if blocks. But it gets the job done.

I never needed to solve the second part of your problem but perhaps you could use a little javascript to dynamically rewrite the whole page with the next step. Sorry but don't have a code example there as I never tried it.